# Why can't I find the preview button in iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, netbeans-8

[image]

As you can see above those are the only buttons I see. There is no preview to see how the report looks like. I'm not sure if I installed everything perfectly but I just added jasperreports-6.2.0 in the libraries and iReport-5.5.0-plugin. My NetBeans version is 8.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I solved it. I downloaded the plug-in here instead http://sourceforge.net/projects/ireport/files/iReport%20Plugin%20for%20NetBeans/iReport-5.6.0/iReport-5.6.0-plugin.zip/download?use_mirror=nchc